# "Хотеть" (управление глагола)

Tags: морфология

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, какое управление у глагола "хотеть"? Как правильно? 
Хочу лето - лета, хочу осень? Хочу маму, хочу торт, мяса, пива... 
Запуталась. По словарям, вроде Р.п. Но как быть с тортом и мамой? 
Как вариант, подумала, может, там опущено  слово, от которого ставится вопрос? 
Например, "хочу (обнять кого?) маму", "хочу (с'есть что?) торт". Тогда В.п.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При глаголах ***хотеть**, ждать, спросить/спрашивать, ожидать, желать, искать, клянчить, просить, требовать, дождаться/дожидаться* и т. п. падеж существительного зависит главным образом от того, определённым или неопределённым является объект, выраженный существительным.

При перечисленных глаголах употребляется форма родительного падежа, если нужно подчеркнуть неопределенность зависимого существительного: *ждать* (чего?) звонка (от кого угодно), *спросить* (чего?) совета (какого-нибудь).

Однако при названных глаголах возможен и винительный падеж управляемого существительного. Он употребляется для обозначения конкретных, определенных предметов: *хочу* (что?) компот, яблочный сок, газированную минеральную воду (а не вообще любого напитка); *ждать* десятый троллейбус или трамвай (а не вообще любого трамвая). В винительном падеже выступают существительные со значением лица, так как здесь всегда ясно, что речь идет о лице вполне конкретном, определённом: *ждать* (кого?) подругу.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Интересно было узнать!

Comment: как же Хотели отмены крепостного права / хотели конституцию отмена - не неопределённое существительное

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что хотеть (чего?) больше всего подходит в тех случаях, когда говорим о съедобных продуктах. Тогда употребляется род. падеж. Например: хочу молока, чаю, сыра, воды - т.е. того, что не штучно. Но хочу: телефон, новую картину, грушу и т.д. Здесь подходит винительный падеж. Ответьте, пожалуйста, как объяснить это иностранным ученикам?

Comment: Смотрите, пожалуйста, ответ пользователя Завада.  Конкретность предмета, продукта, и проч., диктует выбор падежа.  Был ещё вопрос здесь про "купить сыр -- купить сыра", там тоже о том же.  Поищите.